# GCP cloudbuild.yaml: kmsKeyName requires hardcoded value. How can we adapt for separate environments?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

We have a two separate GCP projects (one for dev, and one for prod). We are using CloudBuild to deploy our project by utilizing repo-mirroring and a CloudBuild trigger that fires when ever the dev or prod branches are updated. The cloudbuild.yaml file looks like this:

```
# Firestore security rules deploy
- name: "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase"
  args: ["deploy", "--only", "firestore:rules"]
  secretEnv: ['FIREBASE_TOKEN']

# Firestore indexes deploy
- name: "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase"
  args: ["deploy", "--only", "firestore:indexes"]
  secretEnv: ['FIREBASE_TOKEN']

secrets:
- kmsKeyName: 'projects/my-dev-project/locations/global/keyRings/ci-ring/cryptoKeys/deployment'
  secretEnv:
    FIREBASE_TOKEN: 'myreallylongtokenstring'

timeout: "1600s"
```

The problem we have is that the kmsKeyName apparently needs to be hardcoded in order for GCP to read it, meaning we can't do something like this:

```
secrets:
- kmsKeyName: 'projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/global/keyRings/ci-ring/cryptoKeys/deployment'
  secretEnv:
    FIREBASE_TOKEN: 'myreallylongtokenstring'
```

This does not lend itself well to a continuous-deployment process like the one we are using since we'd like that kmsKeyName string to be dynamically set with the relevant project-id value depending on the dev or prod environment we are deploying to.

Is there a way around this that would allow us to dynamically specify the kmsKeyName?

***Update:***
We have found a quick/dirty solution which was to create individual cloudbuild.yaml files: one for dev (cloudbuild-dev.yaml) and one for prod (cloudbuild-prod.yaml). Each cloudbuild file is identical except for the last part where we specify our hardcoded "secrets" info. 
Explanation: GCP Cloud Build relies on individual triggers for each environment build, and each trigger can be configured to point at a specific cloudbuild yaml file, whcih is what we have done. Dev build trigger points at cloudbuild-dev.yaml, and the production trigger points at cloudbuild-prod.yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I tried different configuration with simple quote, double, without, with substition variables,...

The boring solution is to use the manual decoding as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#decrypting_the_file_during_your_build). But you can use variables and substitution variables as you want

The boring part is that you have to inject the secret in each step which require it, like that (for example as environment variable):

```
- name: "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase"
  entrypoint: "bach"
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - "export FIREBASE_TOKEN=$(cat secrets.json) && firebase deploy --only firestore:rules"
```

I don't know other workaround

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not tried your solution as we are pressed for time but it appears to be viable and probably the best solution if we want to keep things centralized in a single cloudbuild.yaml. I'll mark this as the answer with the caveat that I have not tried it yet.